# Why is my react hook overwriting the current value as apposed to adding multiple key value pairs to my state object?

Tags: reactjs, object, react-hooks, state, mutation

I am attempting to use a map in react to pass props to an element which will include multiple input values. This requires the use of a hook to update changes to the state 'value' which should create an object that includes each input type and its corresponding value.

This is my file containing the child element

```
child.jsx 

const Forms = ({ formType, onFormChange, values, onTypeChange, error }) => {

  const handleChange = useCallback((event) => {
    onTypeChange(formType)
    onFormChange(event)
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <>
    <input className='createform-input' placeholder={formType} name={formType} value= {values.formType} onChange={handleChange} />
    </>
  )
}
export default Forms
```

and here is the parent element

```
parent.jsx
const [value, setForm] = useSetForm(); 
const types = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password']

<form className='create-account-form' onSubmit={e => { e.preventDefault(); }}>
    {types.map((type) => {
         return(
             <Forms
                 formType={type}
                 onFormChange={setForm}
                 onTypeChange={setTypes}
                 values={value}
                 placeholder={type}
                 error={error}
            />
          )
       })}
   <button type='submit' onClick={handleData}>Create Account</button>
</form>
```

and here is the custom hook I am using to update the state values

```
hook.jsx

const useSetForm = () => {
    const [value, setForm] = useState({}); 
    return [value, (event) => { event.preventDefault(); setForm({...value, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })}]
}

export default useSetForm
```

output after updating each input field where the last input field I entered information to was the firstname input.

```
Object { firstname: "jack" }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your `Forms` input value to `values[formType]`, using `values.formType` would return `undefined`:

```
const Forms = ({ formType, onFormChange, values, onTypeChange, error }) => {
  const handleChange = useCallback((event) => {
    onTypeChange(formType);
    onFormChange(event);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        className='createform-input'
        placeholder={formType}
        name={formType}
        value={values[formType]}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </>
  );
};
export default Forms;
```

Also, remove the `event.preventDefault()` from the `setForm` function:

```
const useSetForm = () => {
    const [value, setForm] = useState({});
    return [
      value,
      (event) => {
        setForm((oldValue) => {
          return { ...oldValue, [event.target.name]: event.target.value };
        });
      },
    ];
  };
  
  export default useSetForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

focus on your child component in order to prevent change uncontrolled components to controlled 'cause when starts values[formType] doesn't exists you could do the next:

```
const Forms = ({ formType, onFormChange, values, onTypeChange, error }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("")
      
  const handleChange = useCallback((event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value)
    onTypeChange(formType)
    onFormChange(event)
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <>
      <input className='createform-input' placeholder={formType} name={formType} value= {value} onChange={handleChange} />
    </>
  )
}
```